# Why is this property defined on the prototype--not on the constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

In the chapter on [Bugs and Error Handling in Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net//08_error.html), I found the following piece of code.  I would like to know why the writer set the name property on the prototype--not in the constructor.

```
function InputError(message) {
  this.message = message;
  this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
InputError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
InputError.prototype.name = "InputError";
```

Throughout the book, he has been defining properties in the constructor and methods on the prototype.  Nicholas Zakas recommends doing the same in Ch6 of *Professional Javascript for Web Developers*, because, he says, if you define methods in the constructor, then each call to the constructor creates a new instance of the method.  This is of course the opposite situation--a property being defined on the prototype.

To reiterate: What I want to know is, **why might the author have defined 'name' property on the prototype**?

So far, I've read these two SO posts two no avail.

[What is the difference between assigning a function directly to a constructor versus to it's prototype, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373165/what-is-the-difference-between-assigning-a-function-directly-to-a-constructor-ve)

-This told me what I've already read in the books mentioned above.

[Why defining properties in the prototype is considered an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904203/why-defining-properties-in-the-prototype-is-considered-an-antipattern)

-I didn't really understand this post, but I think it was irrelevant, because it was talking about patterns in other languages.  I am concerned with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why might the author have defined 'name' property on the prototype?

Because every instance of `InputError` shares the same `name`. "Methods" is just a colloquial term for properties who have a function as value (*). *Usually* it is those methods that should be shared between instances, but in some cases (like this one) it might be data as well.

---

*: Meaning, there is no difference between between a *property* and a *method*.

Answer (score 0):

Every `InputError` shares the same name.  The only thing that really needs to change in each new instance is the `message` argument.  In this case, it doesn't really  matter.