# JavaScript titleCase function without regex

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to make a function that takes a string and return a string with all the first latters of a word in uppercase and the rest in lowercase.

Here is what I have:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str.toLowerCase();
  var strAr = str.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < strAr.length; i++) {
    strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  }
  str = strAr.join(" ");
  return str;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

For example, it should change 'My name is nikos' into 'My Name Is Nikos'

Why is the code above not working?

Comment: `str.toLowerCase()` and `strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()` do nothing. You have to save the result of them somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: FYI, this isn't title case. Titles don't have every word capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do an assignment for your string, so the first capital letter then the rest of the string as a lowercase:

```
strAr[i] = strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strAr[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Note the value `strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()` will only return the first character as a capital letter, it will not actually change the string in any way.

[**Here is a simple example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fjrzx6gc/)

Comment: This is the only correct answer because it is the only answer that answered the question "I can't understand why the code above is not working" Everyone else just gave a different solution.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Thanks, I actually didn't notice that the rest of the items need to be converted to lower-case (*if not so already*), fixed. So now it's a correct answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In your for loop you need to assign a value in your loop, like this:

`strAr[i] = strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();`

Another (slightly more organized) way to do this: we will make a function to take a word and capitalize it, then we will make a function that takes a string, splits it on a space, capitalizes each word and rejoins and returns the string. Use it on your own string with `titleCase('hi there')`

```
function capitalize(str) {
  if(str.length == 0) return str;
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}

function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(capitalize).join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because you still need to assign the result of `strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()`:

```
strAr[i] = strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strAr[i].slice(1);
```

It's worth pointing out that the `.toUpperCase()`/`.toLowerCase()` methods [do not mutate/alter the value of the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) (which is why you need to assign it). You can simplify your code to the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/43ds44r0/)

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var strAr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < strAr.length; i++) {
        strAr[i] = strAr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strAr[i].slice(1);
    }
    return strAr.join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase('This is a simple test.'));
// This Is A Simple Test.
```

---

As an alternative to what you wrote, you could also use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gephqhwL/)

```
function titleCase (str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)(\w)/g, function(x) {
    return x.toUpperCase();
  });
}

console.log(titleCase('This is a simple test.'));
// This Is A Simple Test.
```

It will convert the entire input string to lower case, and then capitalize all characters succeeding whitespace (based on the match).

Answer (score 2):

Extends the String class:

Replace every word with a toUpperCase'd version of itself.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
};


console.log("jose maria gonzales".capitalize()); 
// Jose Maria Gonzales
```

Comment: Note, for future stackizens viewing this code, add anything to `prototype` is largely discouraged:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/11904203/1075247

Answer (score 0):

use below code for ucword

```js
        function titleCase(str) {
            return (str + '')
                .replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
                    return $1.toUpperCase();
                });
        }

        var data = titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
        document.write(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.split(' ');
  var title ="";
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    title = str[i].toLowerCase();
    result.push(title[0].toUpperCase()+title.slice(1));
  }
  return result.join(' ');
}
console.log(titleCase('This is a simple test.'));
// This Is A Simple Test.
```

really easy to understand and follow through...

Comment: Please provide an explanation of why this is the correct way to solve the problem in addition to the code above.  Check out [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details on providing good answers.

Answer (score 0):

**A simple ready-to-use JS function for Title case**

```
function toTitleCase(txt = ''){
    if (txt && txt.length > 0) {
      const txtInLC = txt.toLowerCase();
      txt = txtInLC.substring(0,0) + txtInLC[0].toUpperCase() + txtInLC.substring(1);
    }
    return txt;
  };

toTitleCase('HELLO WORLD')
```

---

Some use-cases

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 'hello world' | 'Hello world' |
| 'Hello World' | 'Hello world' |
| 'HELLO World' | 'Hello world' |
| 'hello WORLD' | 'Hello world' |
| 'HELLO WORLD' | 'Hello world' |