# Title Case JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, lowercase, charat

I am trying to create a function in which after toLowerCase() input, will then capitalize the first letter in each element of an array.

```
function title_case ( String ) {
    var result = "";
    var text = String.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      var c = text[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      result = result + c;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Input:

```
document.write( title_case( "a kitty PUrrs") );
```

The resulting output of the current code is AKP. I'm trying to figure out a way to delete lowercase character with charAt(1) and then join() for the output if possible. Am I on the right track? I know there are simpler methods, but I'm trying to learn something along these lines.

Comment: one thing I wouldn't do is have `String` as the argument name - I mean, you can, but don't. .. the whole function is simply `const title_case = s => s.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1)).join(' ')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript titleCase function without regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766968/javascript-titlecase-function-without-regex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of deleting the first character, you can make a substring of the rest of the string after the first character. I.e.:

```
result = result + c + text[i].substring(1, text[i].length()-1) + " ";
```

The `text[i].substring(1, text[i].length()-1)` gets the part of the word from the second character to the end of the word (kind of like "deleting" the first character).

And you don't need a `join()` function for strings, just `+` for concatenation. The `" "` at the end separates the words with spaces. At the end of the function, you can return `result.trim()` to get rid of the last space.

Comment: Thank you so much! This put me on the right track. I really appreciate you also explaining further on concatenation and the logic behind the coding. This was fantastic help. Thank you!

Comment: @Val7x I'm glad the explanation helped!

Answer (score 1):

Use the below functions to just capitalise a sentence or title case a sentence.

```
console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter("THIS IS A SENTENCE")); //converts a sentence to capitalise. 

console.log(titleCase("THIS IS A SENTENCE")); //converts a sentence to titlecase. 

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function titleCase(string) {
    return string.split(" ").map(x => capitalizeFirstLetter(x)).join(" ");
}
```

Comment: This would blow up when passed an empty string.